# Videos not playing on any mobile devices with ios and android versions but playing on the web pages

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone

I have created the below `javascript` code to load videos into my web page as a pop up. The videos are loading and playing perfectly fine on the browsers, but due to some issues, they are not playing on mobile devices.

Attaching the code for the same.

```
 var bodyLightBox = document.getElementById("bodyLightBox");
 var modalBoxWapper = document.getElementById("modalBoxWapper");
 var modalBox = document.getElementById("modalBox");
 var pageBody = document.getElementById("body");

 var videoWrapper = document.getElementById("videoWrapper");

 var currCont ="";
 var boxHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

 var videoCont ="";


 function openModalBox(conId, divWidth){    
     contDiv = document.getElementById(conId);
     currCont = contDiv;

     bodyLightBox.style.display="block";
     bodyLightBox.style.height = boxHeight+"px";

     modalBoxWapper.style.display="block";
     modalBox.style.width = divWidth;
     currCont.style.display="block";

     pageBody.style.overflow="hidden";
 }

 function closeModalBox(id){    
     bodyLightBox.style.display="none";
     modalBoxWapper.style.display="none";
     currCont.style.display="none";
     pageBody.style.overflow="auto";     
 } 

 function openVideoModalBox(divID, videoTitle, videoURLID, videoDivWidth){

     bodyLightBox.style.display="block";
     bodyLightBox.style.height = boxHeight+"px";

     modalBoxWapper.style.display="block";
     modalBox.style.width = videoDivWidth;  

     createVideoWrapper(divID, videoTitle, videoURLID);
     //alert(divID);
     videoCont = document.getElementById(divID);
     videoCont.style.display="block";

     pageBody.style.overflow="hidden";
 }

 function closeVideoModalBox(id){   
     bodyLightBox.style.display="none";
     modalBoxWapper.style.display="none";
     videoCont.style.display="none";     
     pageBody.style.overflow="auto";

     removeDiv(videoWrapper, id);
 }

function createVideoWrapper(divID, videoTitle, videoURLID){

     var div = document.createElement('div');
     videoWrapper.appendChild(div);
     div.setAttribute('id', divID);
     div.styly ='display: none;';

     var titleDiv = document.createElement('div');
     div.appendChild(titleDiv);
     titleDiv.setAttribute("className", 'topBar'); // className use for ie7
     titleDiv.setAttribute("class", 'topBar');  // this worked all
     titleDiv.innerHTML='<div class="modalBoxtitle" id="modalBoxtitle">'+videoTitle+'</div><div class="closeBtn" onclick="closeVideoModalBox('+divID+')">X</div><div style="clear: both;"><!--  --></div>';

     var videoCont = document.createElement('div');
     div.appendChild(videoCont);
     videoCont.setAttribute("className", 'video_contWapper'); // className use for ie7
     videoCont.setAttribute("class", 'video_contWapper');  // this worked all
     videoCont.innerHTML='<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="480" width="640" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoURLID+'?autoplay=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoURLID+'?autoplay=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param><embed height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoURLID+'?autoplay=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" id="ytplayer01"></embed></object>';
    //videoCont.innerHTML='<iframe width="640" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoURLID+'?autoplay=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen><!--  --></iframe>';

     var emptyDiv = document.createElement('div');
     div.appendChild(emptyDiv);
     emptyDiv.style.clear="both";
     emptyDiv.innerHTML="<!--  -->";
 }

// remove video div
function removeDiv(parent, child){
        parent.removeChild(child);
    }
```

Awaiting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you embedding a flash player on this page (which is bad/not supported on mobile device) ?

If you want video to play smooth on mobile device browers, you should better use the `<video>` tag with appropriate video format (h264 for example).

Comment: As far as I know, ios converts flash videos into quick time videos and I have practically done and seen that, but could not figure out why this one is not working. - @Baart

Comment: @Nathan: Android does not do that though

Comment: So is there a way to play vidoes on iphone and android with my above code? - @wiz3kid

Comment: I did use the video tag, but then too I am not able to play them. - @Baart

Comment: @Nathan I see you are referencing a YouTube video. YouTube has various APIs for playing and embedding its videos under the Developers link at the bottom of the home page. In addition, they have an experimental HTML5 player option at http://www.youtube.com/html5 which you can inspect. You might also want to ask your question in the appropriate Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers

Comment: Can you provide me an example with reference to my code so that I can integrate and check? - @wiz3kid

Comment: @Nathan No, sorry, I haven't personally worked with video on the web, I just mentioned a few places you can look at.